# Dividing a file into separate files with 10,000 lines each

Tags: bash

I have a file which is too large for the software I am using, so I want to cut it into smaller parts. It is a plain text file. How can I cut it into seperate files. E.g.:

- `output1.txt` contains the first 10,000 lines of the original file.
- `output2.txt` contains the next 10,000 lines of the original file.
- etc.
- The last file would probably have less than 10,000 lines.
- If I wanted to join them back, I'd just use `cat output*.txt > joined.tex`.

How can I split the file in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [split](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html)

E.g.

```
split -l 10000 originalfile.txt
```